# Regex - starts with one of list of characters and has length between 1 and 3 symbols, ending with whitespace or end of line

Tags: regex

I am cleaning data where I want to detect all characters starting with 'i' or 'f' and with length between 1 and 3.

Example (ignore the meaning of the text):

- payment for **i** date
- payment for **inv** date
- payment for **f**

I need to catch the bold string.

This is what I have so far but it is not getting the long string *inv*

```
\s[i|f]{1}|\s[i|f]{2}|\s[i|f]{3}
```

Comment: You can use: `\b[if]\w{0,2}\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple regex:

```bash
\b[if]\p{L}{0,2}\b
```

Or if you want ignore case matches then use:

```bash
\b[ifIF]\p{L}{0,2}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WLHRXH/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `[if]`: Match `i` or `f`
- `[ifIF]`: Match `i` or `f` or `I` or `F`
- `\p{L}{0,2}`: Match 0 to 2 unicode letters
- `\b`: Word boundary